# MSACCESS DateTIme SQL QUERY

Tags: c#, sql, .net, ms-access, oledb

I am from India (it may has something to do with culture info here). I am building a desktop application in C#.Net 2010 Express with MS-ACCESS 2010 32 bit as backend. I am using OLEDB for db connectivity.
I have a column named dt as Date/Time which has following values:

20-09-2016 22:53:32
19-08-2016 22:54:24
20-09-2016 22:56:01
22-09-2016 22:56:27
22-09-2016 22:56:41

I need to fetch the records By Date, By Month and By Year.
Till now I am not able to complete the Date part so couldnt work on month and year. Following is my code:

```
b.com.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM srvtrans WHERE DateTime.Parse(dt)=@a ORDER BY sno DESC";
b.com.Parameters.Add("@a", dtp_srdmy.Value.ToShortDateString());
Show(dtp_srdmy.Value.ToShortDateString());
b.con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
 con.Close();
mytemp = new DataTable();
da.Fill(mytemp);
```

I have also tried following variations:

```
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),dt,111)=@a

WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),dt,101)=@a

WHERE dt LIKE '%@a%' 

WHERE DateTime.Parse(dt)=@a 

WHERE dt=DateValue(@a)

WHERE CAST(dt AS DATE)=@a

WHERE CONVERT(varchar, dt, 101)=@a

WHERE DATE(dt)=@a

WHERE dt=@a
```

but none of them works for me. Please reply what updation should be made in the sql query to fetch records by date, by month and by year. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In addition look at the line `b.con.State == ConnectionState.Closed`, you check for closed and then close it again after. What you should do is create a new OleDbConnection when needed and wrap this in a using block. See [Best Practices - Executing Sql Statements](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/.net/3589/ado-net/14261/best-practices-executing-sql-statements) which has some tips on how to best structure your ado.net code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should work definitely:

```
  b.com.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM srvtrans WHERE DATEVALUE(dt)=DATEVALUE(@a) ORDER BY sno DESC";
  b.com.Parameters.Add("@a", dtp_srdmy.Value);
```

Upvote if this helps.

Answer (score 3):

```
b.com.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM srvtrans WHERE dt = @a ORDER BY sno DESC";
b.com.Parameters.Add(new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@a", OleDbType.DBDate) {Value = dtp_srdmy.Value });
con.Open();
```

- You want to pass in the native types and not string representations of the types for your parameter values. I am assuming that `dtp_srdmy` is probably a user control (*as pointed out by `@Gord Thompson` in the comments below probably a DateTimePicker*) or other type where `Value` is a property that returns a `DateTime` instance.
- You want to compare directly, the underlying store/provider will handle the comparison for you so do not try to wrap your values in ticks, quotes, or something else or try to do the conversion for the store engine.
- You should specify the underlying access type using the `OleDbType` enumeration, I guessed it was `DBDate` but I could be wrong, please correct it if necessary.
- Open your connection before you execute any commands. I assume you are using a data adapter but did not see it, make sure it is associated with your Command. I omitted this part of the code as it was not relevant to the question.

Comment: *"I am assuming that `dtp_srdmy` is a nullable DateTime instance"* - The "dtp_" prefix suggests that it is a `DateTimePicker` object whose [.Value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value(v=vs.110).aspx) property is a `DateTime`. Still an excellent answer, though. +1

Comment: @GordThompson - ah hah, that makes more sense. Thanks!

Comment: Hi. I am sorry for mistakenly written con.close(). I have changes it to b.con.Open(); and yes, dtp is a c#.net datetimepicker control. Dataadapter is present and bound in a separate class. I tried the above suggestion with datareader and datadapter, but still getting 0 rows.